# Could anyone tell me how to calculate ratio face

Tags: ios, opencv, face

I heard that OpenCV support Face Detection but how after detected face, we could possible to get position of the eyes, mouth, nose to calculate ratio. Thanks so much.

Comment: Help yourselves instead of relying on strangers.  https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html

Comment: Documentation is a wonderful thing. You should try it.

Comment: I wrote a commercial face morphing app using Apple's CIDetector (type CIDetectorTypeFace) , and knew exactly zero about it until I read the docs.

Comment: thanks nice guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a library like [dlib](http://dlib.net/) to detect face landmarks, and then use the landmarks to calculate ratios. OpenCV does not have support for landmark detection yet.

If you are familar with Swift, [this post](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/face-and-faces-landmarks-detection-using-vision-framework-in-ios-11) is a very godo tutorial for face landmark detection using iOS Vision SDK.

Comment: thanks Totoro, but it written by C++, I  try to find the way to handle in iOS device

Comment: This is a good place to get started https://github.com/shaileshh/Mirror. This uses a slightly older version of dlib, but integration has already been done. Will edit the answer to add other options in iOS.

Comment: Thanks so much. You saved my day ^^